# What do countries do to ensure that R&D budget for science or technology in general coming from the government is spent effectively?

Tags: government, corruption, finance

What do countries do to ensure that R&D budget for science or technology in general coming from the government is spent effectively? Often countries give a 1+ billion stimulus package for R&D only to observe that companies are using the money for things that are not related to R&D or does not contribute to R&D innovation such as buying a large real estate office in a big city without using the money for R&D whatsoever. What are the things government do to maximize the effect of such a big capital injection?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "R&D". I'll pick one example, the James Webb Space Telescope. Was that an R&D project? The R&D had been done decades ago, yet the JWST was severely over budget. I see that as a construction project as as opposed to an R&D project. R&D is typically a tiny sliver of the budget of an organization such as NASA whose entire focus in a sense is R&D. Stimulus packages usually are not used on R&D projects. R&D is slow. ("If we knew what we were doing we wouldn't call it research".) They're used on construction or some other concept where monies can be spent quickly.

Comment: It would be helpful to point to specific agencies responsible for handing out the funds. There are many ways to get research funding and many other ways to get subsidies. Each of them will have their own monitoring system. You mention a 1+ billion stimulus package for R&D, what package was that?

Comment: What specifically are you talking about? The procedures are different for e.g. (1) direct grants for specific (often military) projects (2) funding via universities and other funding bodies/programs like the EU's Horizon which are not directly controlled by government, (3) tax credits for R&D spending (which are typically administered by tax authorities) (4) spending by regional, state, or local development agencies, (5) specific/emergency purposes like COVID which operate outside normal procedures by special laws or emergency powers, (6) a variety of partnerships with charities, companies...

Comment: So three comments asking for specifics. If the OP specified a particular grant issued on a particular day by a particular agency, would you be able to answer?  If there are different methods for different types of grants from different agencies, why don't you include that in your answer?

Comment: Why are you picking out R&D as a specific item? R&D is a tiny portion of a government's budget. Corruption, fraud, and abuse are much more likely on large scale projects, Two examples are weapons contracts and management (e.g., in multiple countries, the defense department or the defense contractors have reportedly sold weaponry to drug cartels), and stimulus packages to keep businesses alive during the covid pandemic (e.g., there has reportedly been a good amount of fraud in both the Trump and Biden administrations' stimulus packages). Building weapons and stimulating businesses is not R&D.

Comment: @BobaFit I ask for specifics because it is unclear to me, if the question is talking about research grants, which have a specific purpose, or general subsidies, which may be *intended* by the government to go into research but do not necessarily come with restrictions on their use. If the goal of the government is to retain a technological edge over other countries, a new office building for an innovative company may be just what the government wanted.

Comment: Countries ensuring their money is spent efficiently?  does not compute.  I doubt most government funds are spent anywhere near efficiently.

Comment: Odd to see so many downvotes.  *Effective* government R&D spending is a major tool for improving productivity, thus ultimately standards of living and country wealth.  Yet a lot of doesn't seem all that well used or targeted and ends up being more business subsidies to well-connected firms.  This is a *major* policy differentiator between rich countries.  As a blunder, I'd cite the EU's *analog* [HDTV](https://www.live-production.tv/case-studies/sports/brief-review-hdtv-europe-early-90%E2%80%99s.html) initiative in the 1990s.  Japan's 5th Generation computing initiative too.

Comment: Canada's way to claim R&D tax credits is also very loosey-goosey, with just about anything vaguely innovative, including internal-only projects, likely to qualify.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica True R&D projects inevitably have a high failure rate. "If we knew what we were doing we wouldn't call it research." Most companies that support internal R&D at the expense of profit do so with the expectation that a small portion of those internal R&D projects will succeed and bring even greater profit in the future. Such companies brutally cut the number of R&D projects that move forward. Many government organizations are similarly brutal. Most projects are cut because it doesn't appear that a successful outcome is in the future.

Comment: @DavidHammen I've had the occasion of sitting in on a few corporate meetings trying to suck at government teats and that has soured my view.  True R&D has failures, that is part of it.  But a lot of what gets passed off to the govt as R&D is not truly innovative or research - the fact that it succeeds or not has nothing to with it.  And when taxpayers pay for non-R&D as R&D, that pisses me off.  Hence my support for this question.  For rich Western countries, the numbers are not small either:  https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/GB.XPD.RSDV.GD.ZS

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I've also participated in multiple R&D meetings. Multiple NASA SBIR and STTR project requests obviously are targeted at an existing contractor and are not anywhere close to R&D. (We've learned to read between the lines and avoid those.) SBIRs and STTRs are very limited in funding, particularly so with phase I proposals. But those research projects are tiny. We also do internal R&D, also tiny. NASA also funds internal research, also tiny. I still don't understand why the OP focuses on R&D when that is so small.

Comment: @DavidHammen respectfully, rather than commenting so much, why not write an answer?  Our experience w R&D has limited overlap.  My original comment was only to support this Q getting asked, as it had a fair number of DVs at the time.  Now we are arguing whether NASA contrators do R&D or not ...  In fact, it almost looks like you might be tending in the direction of my answer in your PoV, except you seem to have more experience with the matter.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I have no answer because I don't like this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are numerous tools available to governments (generally speaking) to ensure that grants of money (for whatever purpose) are being used appropriately.  They will vary in-situ as various commenters have observed.

### Reporting Requirements

Virtually every government grant comes with requirements that you [make regular reports](https://www.nsf.gov/pubs/2016/nsf16040/nsf16040.jsp) about how the money was spent, what the fruits of that spending were, and especially any financial benefits you were able to realize from it.

### Audits

Generally speaking, governments have a standing power to demand audits from taxpayers and frequently narrowly-scoped audits are a right reserved by governments when making grants of funds. e.g. [The CDC requires grantees to make regular reports and if the dollar values are high enough, to have such reports audited.](https://www.cdc.gov/grants/welcome-packet/reporting-audit-requirements/index.html)

### Clawbacks

If, at any point, the government concludes that the money was ill-spent (usually in an egregious manner), [they can make you give it back](https://www.carmarthenshire.gov.wales/home/business/funding/business-growth-recovery-grant/claw-back-when-you-may-have-to-repay-the-grant/).... even if you've already spent every penny.  Just the *threat* of a clawback is enough to keep the vast majority of would-be bad actors in line because a late clawback is financially disruptive in the extreme.

### Criminal Investiation

All else failing, the government can [accuse a grant recipient of outright fraud and proceed with a standard criminal investigation](https://www.justice.gov/usao-ma/pr/mit-professor-arrested-and-charged-grant-fraud).  Defrauding the government is the sort of thing they're *especially* keen to punish.

Much of the rhetoric around waste in government spending is not founded in fact but instead in the speaker's disagreement with the particular values expressed by what research is being funded.  Grant programs aren't perfect, but deliberate abuse of the system will get you in hot water sooner, rather than later.

Comment: I would add the grant application procedures themselves, as gatekeepers.  Good ones should be set up to weed out exactly the OP's kind of concerns, as well as commit the recipients to at least some direction of action.  Some accounting software is also able to track grant funding - ie cash from account X can used to buy lab equipment, not office renos.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I waffled on that one. Ultimately I decided not to include it because the OP asks specifically presuming abuse *has* occurred, which presumes that failsafe has failed. But I agree with your point, generally.

Comment: If you go by the title, rather than the body, I think it qualifies.  Fraud and abuse is one thing that comes to mind, but the Q also has a more general interpretation of "how to spend wisely".

Comment: I agree with the other comment. As the question currently stands, talking about the "grant application process" (solicitation/acceptance) as a gatekeeping method, to ensure responsible government spending, is on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

In any decision on how to spend public R&D wisely, the notion of [additionality](https://www.offsetguide.org/high-quality-offsets/additionality/) `*` also needs to be taken into account.

i.e: **Would the project have taken place without government $$$?**

In free markets, a private computer company will... do R&D to make better computers to sell more of them to make more money.  They don't necessarily need government money to do so and in fact pushing government money to established, [well-connected, firms using old technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HD-MAC) `**` may hurt new innovators.

If you have $2B to hand out and $1B went to fund projects that companies would have funded internally anyway, then, from the PoV of the taxpayer, the end result is not very different from burning $1B, or having it vanish through fraud:  **you did not spend that $1B supporting research that really needed it.**

This is a fuzzy, hard to pin down, and hard to solve concept, but, IMHO, likely more of a problem than outright fraud.  Which is sexier to talk about.

`*` Not sure additionality is the best term, but I have often seen the issue of not funding would-have-happened-anyway projects mentioned wrt carbon offsets.  I assume there's a better term in economic theory - I'll adjust based on suggestions.

`**` I think the analogue HDTV subsidies to major EU firms was due to spend $20B.  Not sure how much was used before the project cratered.